# How to change the color (automatically) in the line graph using R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate a line graph from my data (Year and Rain). The graph is fine but I want to change (automatically) the color of every line. The code is given below

```
ggplot(data=data_1, aes(x=Year, y=rain, fill=Year)) 
 + geom_line(stat="identity") 
 + theme_minimal() 
 + geom_col(width = 0.05, position = position_dodge(0.7)) 
 + xlab("Year") 
 + ylab("Rain") 
 + ggtitle("Rain of every Year")
```

I am trying to use
`scale_fill_brewer(palette="Oranges")` but it showing error. `Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale`.

My graph without `scale_fill_brewer(palette="Oranges")` is given below

My Code Generated RGraph:
[image]

I need to draw like one this (this graph is dewan using Python!)

My Expected Graph:
[image]

Could you tell me, how can I do that?

Comment: If you kindly share a sample of `data_1` with `dput(data_1)` we can help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (No output provided due to lack of reproducible data):

```
#Code
ggplot(data=data_1, aes(x=Year, y=rain, fill=factor(Year)))+
  geom_line(stat="identity")+
  theme_minimal()+
  geom_col(width = 0.05, position = position_dodge(0.7))+
  xlab("Year")+
  ylab("Rain")+
  ggtitle("Rain of every Year")+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 1))
```

Comment: Hello, it works! Thank you very much. However, is it possible to show all year one after another (using this code it is showing 3 columns) but I want 1 column!

Comment: @user3291513 Yes it is possible, I will add the code for that.

Comment: @user3291513 I have added an update for the legend issue using `guides()` please check and let me know if that works!

Comment: it works, but, unfortunately, some are missing due to the lack of space!

Comment: @user3291513 Try `ncol=2` !! That should fix in any way the issue!

Comment: Thank you very much. I accepted you and. However, is it possible, if put my cursor on any line it will show from the "Y-axis"?

Comment: @user3291513 It is possible, I would suggest checking these two packages `plotly` and `ggplotly`. Overall the last package can easily transform `ggplot2` objects to what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing real data it's difficult to say but I would try `geom_segment`. Here is code with made up, test data.

```
set.seed(2020)
data_1 <- data.frame(Year = 1900:1950, 
                     rain = sample(400:1000, length(1900:1950), TRUE))

ggplot(data = data_1, aes(x = Year, y = 0)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = Year, yend = rain, color = factor(Year)), 
               show.legend = FALSE) +
  xlab("Year") + 
  ylab("Rain") + 
  ggtitle("Rain of every Year") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But, no improvement. However, I think (from another comment) if we use "theme_minimal()"  after "geom_segment" it is working!

Comment: @user3291513 See now, `theme_minimal` at the end should work.